# Able to Ping Remote Server, Yet Unable to Connect

Tags: mysql, database, database-connection, remote-server

I'm able to ping the remote server I am attempting to connect to successfully. However, when running the MySQL command:

```
mysql -u monty -h website.com -p
```

I receive the following error:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'website.com' (111)
```

I've followed the instructions found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-users.html) that show how to create a user with necessary privileges:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'monty'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'localhost'
->     WITH GRANT OPTION;
mysql> CREATE USER 'monty'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'%'
->     WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

I've also commented out the following line in /etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
# bind-address      = 127.0.0.1
```

Even so, I'm still unable to connect remotely. Is there something I'm missing here? Thanks again all.

Comment: (please notice in most cases you don't want to do that anyway)

Comment: Lohoris, are you referring to the flush privileges command?

Comment: Did you restart MySQL server after commenting out `bind-address`? If not, please do.

Comment: Marc, yep I certainly did restart the server.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring in general to "connecting to a remote mysql server". There are many occasion where it makes sense to do it, of course, but often newbies try to do it when they really shouldn't, hence my (unclear) comment.

Comment: Ah thank you for the clarification Lohoris. In that case, if I have a downloadable program that users can download on their client machines, how do I give them the ability to upload content without exposing any holes?

Comment: @VincentRusso, consider using a middle tier (application server), and provide an API, rather than giving client applications direct access to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error `111` is `Connection refused`:

```
$ perror 111
111: Connection refused
```

There's a few common ways this happens:

- The server system, the client system, or a router in the middle is configured to administratively `REJECT` these packets. TCP packets are handled differently than ICMP packets, so being able to `ping` does not necessarily imply the ability to route any random TCP stream. Ask admins on the systems to check `ufw` or `iptables` for firewalling data.
- The server system is running a  [mandatory access control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control) tool such as  [AppArmor](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor/), [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux), [TOMOYO](http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/index.html.en), or [SMACK](http://schaufler-ca.com/) that is configured to forbid packets. These systems vary in how errors are reported, but check `/var/log/audit/audit.log` and `dmesg(1)` output for `reject`, `denied`, `AVC`, etc.
- You may have removed only one `bind-address` configuration. Try adding an explicit [`bind-address=0.0.0.0`](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aNWjDyG88KDIJ%3adev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=ubuntu) (Google cache link; I cannot contact `dev.mysql.com` for some reason) to the configuration file to force binding to all addresses. Check `netstat -anp | grep -i mysql` to see which ports, if any, it is listening to.

Comment: The explicit `bind-address` config and `netstat` are both great suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

It is not a permission problem. If it were a permission problem, you would get a different error.

It is a connection problem.

Ensure that the line `skip-networking` line is commented out or removed from your config file.

Ensure that the `port` line is configured to the proper port (default is 3306).

If you're still unable to connect, then it's most likely a firewall/ISP issue.

Pinging is not really a good test because it only tests if the ICMP server is up. Using telnet to connect to the specific port would be a better test:

```
> telnet website.com 3306
```

There are many places that you can put a `my.cnf` file, so search for the file to ensure another file isn't in effect.

This combined with sarnold's answer should get you on the right track.